# I want to get part of this string but it should break on previous whole word. It should not cut on mid-words

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is my code:

```
def strprevword(str, count):
    new = str[0:count]
    print(new)
```

1. `strprevword("The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.",8)`
2. `strprevword("The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.",3)`
3. `strprevword("The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.",15)`

In the first two cases, output should be 'The'
In the third case output should be 'The greatest'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def extract_words(paragraph, limit):
    length_counter = 0
    collect_words = []
    for word in paragraph.split():
        if length_counter + len(word) <= limit:
            length_counter += len(word)
            collect_words.append(word)
        else:
            break
    return " ".join(collect_words)


sample_string = "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall."

print(extract_words(sample_string, 8))
print(extract_words(sample_string, 3))
print(extract_words(sample_string, 15))
```

Output:

```
The
The
The greatest
```